# How to use isDisable of SelectOption

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I have a SelectOption and I'm populating like this:
maintNotesList.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf('Default'),'Select Description'));

I tried to insert the isDisabled for this value so he can be the first one like this:
maintNotesList.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf('Default'),'Select Description'), isDisabled(true));

But isn't working. I receive this error:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isDisabled(Boolean).

How can I insert isDisabled for this value in a select option list?
I view this option in the documentation but I can see a example for this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_pages_selectoption.htm

Comment: Please post your code so that any one can understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that isDisabled() is not a method for the SelectOption Apex Class (as per the documentation). If you want to have a SelectOption that is disabled, you can create the SelectOption just by passing a value of **true** for the third parameter of the constructor:

```
maintNotesList.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf('Default'),'Select Description'), true);
```